# Why python IDLE and Console produce different results

Tags: python

I write a simple Python script to translate Chinese Punctuation to English.

```
import codecs, sys

def trcn():
    tr = lambda x: x.translate(str.maketrans("""，。！？；：、（）【】『』「」﹁﹂“”‘’《》～￥…—×""", """,.!?;:,()[][][][]""''<>~$^-*"""))
    out = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
    for line in sys.stdin:
        out.write(tr(line))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("usage:\n\t{0} STDIN STDOUT".format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(-1)
    trcn()
    sys.exit(0)
```

But something is wrong with **UNICODE**.
I cannot get it passed. Error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trcn.py", line 13, in <module>
    trcn()
  File "trcn.py", line 7, in trcn
    out.write(tr(line))
  File "C:\Python31\Lib\codecs.py", line 356, in write
    self.stream.write(data)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

After then, I test the **out.write()** in IDLE and Console.
They produced different results.
I don't know why.

**In IDLE**

```
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79149, Mar 21 2010, 00:41:52) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import sys,codecs
>>> out = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
>>> out.write('hello')
hello
>>>
```

**In Console**

```
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79149, Mar 21 2010, 00:41:52) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys,codecs
>>> out = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
>>> out.write('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python31\Lib\codecs.py", line 356, in write
    self.stream.write(data)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
>>>
```

---

**Platform: Windows XP EN**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your encoded output is coming out of the encoder as bytes, and therefore must be passed to `sys.stdout.buffer`:

```
out = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout.buffer)
```

I'm not entirely sure why your code acts differently in IDLE versus the console, but the above may help. Perhaps IDLE's `sys.stdout` actually expects bytes instead of characters (hopefully it has a `.buffer` that also expects bytes).

Comment: Thank you! This has been driving me nuts for 2 days. I was trying "out = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)" It would work on Linux but not in Windows (not even in cygwin)

Answer (score 1):

IDLE redirects the stdout to its own GUI output. It apparently accepts bytes as well as strings, which normal stdout doesn't.

Either decode it to Unicode, or print it to sys.stdout.buffer.

Answer (score -1):

It is very well obvious that the console's encoding is not utf-8. there is a way to specify the encoding as optional parameter when invoking python in console. just look for it in python docs.

Comment: thank you. i was with assumption that codecs output was unicode string and NOT bytes.now it is a lot clear.